# Compute the number of molecules

Tags: c++, beginner, homework

I would like my program to be reviewed. I had to write a simple program that calculates the number of molecules in a hydrocarbon.

- 1 carbon atom has 12 AMU.
- 1 hydrogen atom has 1 AMU.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    cout << "Enter mass of hydrocarbon (in grams)\n"
            "followed by the number of carbon atoms\n"
            "followed by the number of hydrogen atoms\n"
            "(e.g. 10.5 2 6): " << flush;

    float mass;
    float carbonAtoms;
    int hydrogenAtoms;
    cin >> mass >> carbonAtoms >> hydrogenAtoms;

    long formulaWght = (carbonAtoms * 12) + (hydrogenAtoms * 1);


    double molecules = (mass / formulaWght) * 6.02e23;



    cout << mass << " grams of hydrocarbon\nwith "
            << carbonAtoms << " carbon atom(s) and "
               << hydrogenAtoms << " hydrogen atom(s)\ncontains "
                  << molecules << " molecules" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Do not use `using namespace std`. Read
   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
2. Instead of using "magic numbers" in your program. Use symbolic
   constants. `CARBON_AMU` and `HYDROGEN_AMU` should be `int`s.

   ```
   const int CARBON_AMU= 12;
   const int HYDROGEN_AMU = 1;
   const double AVOGADRO = 6.02214141070409084099072e23;
   ```
3. Utilize functions in your program, instead of initializing a
   variable with an expression:

   ```
   long formulaWeight(int carbonAtoms, int hydrogenAtoms){
       return((carbonAtoms * CARBON_AMU) + (hydrogenAtoms * HYDROGEN_AMU));
   }

   double numMolecules(float mass, long formulaWeight)
   {
       return((mass / formulaWeight) * AVOGADRO);
   }
   ```
4. `(e.g. 10.5 2 6): " << flush;`

   I don't see any advantage in using `std::flush`. You can remove it.
5. Fix your indentation. This is much easier to read:

   ```
   cout << mass << " grams of hydrocarbon\nwith "
        << carbonAtoms << " carbon atom(s) and "
        << hydrogenAtoms << " hydrogen atom(s)\ncontains "
        << molecules << " molecules" << endl;
   ```

Comment: You could also mention that `carbonAtoms` should be an `int`.

Comment: Also, I think the first indentation example is easier to read.  The second one is better aligned, but is kinda mixed up.

Comment: in simple code like this, I don't see any issue use 'using namespace std;'

Comment: It can become a bad habit and should be stopped early on. This question is tagged `beginner` too.

Answer (score 2):

Some small addendums.

All the parentheses on these lines are unnecessary, because in C++ (and most languages, if not all) multiplication has higher precedence than addition:

> ```
> long formulaWght = (carbonAtoms * 12) + (hydrogenAtoms * 1);
> double molecules = (mass / formulaWght) * 6.02e23;
> ```

And by the way, why multiply by 1?

This is equivalent:

```
long formulaWght = carbonAtoms * 12 + hydrogenAtoms;
double molecules = mass / formulaWght * 6.02e23;
```

---

In addition to the recommendation by @EngieOP to reindent the last `cout`,
I would recommend to rearrange the lines in a way that the embedded `\n` characters appear at the end of code lines, like they will be in the output, like this:

```
cout << mass << " grams of hydrocarbon\n"
     << "with " << carbonAtoms << " carbon atom(s) and "
     << hydrogenAtoms << " hydrogen atom(s)\n"
     << "contains " << molecules << " molecules" << endl;
```

---

Instead of `using namespace std`, if you want to be able to reference simply `cout` and `endl`, you could do this acceptable way:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```